# How to detect specific Keys pressed in a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a text box in my form that I want to detect if specific character pressed in key board like <kbd>%</kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd> ,... that need <kbd>Shift</kbd> key press.

How I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Use can do it as below***

```
    private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

                if (e.KeyChar == '%')
                {
                    //your further code ...
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do exactly, you would either use the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event or you would create a class that derives from TextBox, override the [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) method, and handle the WM_CHAR message.

Answer (score 1):

in `KeyUp` event you can find `Shift` atribute in KeyEventArgs (`e.Shift`). Or you could check if `e.KeyValue` is in given range